# SQLite Select when value is not on another table

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a list of players that can be added to an event. 
I would like to select a list of players not already on the events list.
The Query I have is:

```
    stmt.executeQuery("SELECT PLAYER_NO,FIRST_NAME,SURNAME,"
                + "EMAIL,PHONE_NO FROM PLAYER"
                + "WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT PLAYER_NO FROM EVENT_PLAYER_LIST "
                + "WHERE EVENT_NO = "+eventKey+" & "
                + "EVENT_PLAYER_LIST.PLAYER_NO = PLAYER.PLAYER_NO);");
```

Can anyone spot the problem or tell me how to go about this?

Here are the two tables evolved:

```
    String sql = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EVENT_PLAYER_LIST"
                    + " (EVENT_NO       INT     NOT NULL,"
                    + " PLAYER_NO       INT     NOT NULL,"
                    + " ACTIVE          INT,"
                    + " TIME_ENROLLED   CHAR(50),"
                    + " WINS            INT,"
                    + " LOSES           INT,"
                    + " DRAWS           INT,"
                    + " PRIMARY KEY (EVENT_NO, PLAYER_NO))";


    String sql = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PLAYER"
                    + " (PLAYER_NO       INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY    AUTOINCREMENT      NOT NULL,"
                    + " FIRST_NAME      CHAR(50)    NOT NULL,"
                    + " SURNAME         CHAR(50)    NOT NULL,"
                    + " DOB             CHAR(50),"
                    + " CLUB            CHAR(50),"
                    + " EMAIL           CHAR(120),"
                    + " PHONE_NO        CHAR(50))";
```

If I have several players added to an event they all still show up on the list of players except the first one.

Comment: Show us the structure of the tables (`.schema`),

Comment: It starts with no space after `FROM PLAYER`

Comment: Don't build queries using Strings and `+`. Use prepared statements.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Is the statement throwing an exception or does it not return the data you expected?

Comment: Thanks  juergen d the missing space helped but the statement is still not returning what I'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query should be:

```
stmt.executeQuery("SELECT PLAYER_NO,FIRST_NAME,SURNAME,"
                + "EMAIL,PHONE_NO FROM PLAYER"
                + "WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT PLAYER_NO FROM EVENT_PLAYER_LIST "
                + "WHERE EVENT_NO = "+eventKey+" AND "
                + "EVENT_PLAYER_LIST.PLAYER_NO = PLAYER.PLAYER_NO);");
```

Note the use of **AND** instead of **$**. The latter is the [Bitwise AND](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_bitwise_operators.htm)

Note that the way you are constructing your query is not the best and you are usually advised to use prepared statements instead (for both security and performance reasons)

Comment: NO, it should *not* use `"+eventKey+"`.

Comment: `eventKey` is obviously an argument to the query. OP is probably asking for a query that returns players not in a certain event. Of course on should not construct queries like that (but instead use prepares statements), however this fact does not alter the semantics of the query

Comment: An answer that is semantically correct but teaches dangerous programming habits can not be correct.

Comment: That depends on your perspective. I agree that I should add an edit to my post which I will do. However in my view an answer that does not strictly adhere to best practices but instead just addresses the issue that OP mentioned, is correct

Comment: Thanks that worked. I will use prepared statements in the future.

Comment: @Paddy Glad to hear it!